# rdlc REPORTPARAMETER INT , report doesn't appear

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have written this procedure :

```
   alter proc rel_geralAC (@emite int, @mes char, @ano varchar(4) )as
   select Total_Mun = COUNT(xMunIni),xMunIni ,
   UF = MAX(UFIni) ,Valor_Total = SUM(CAST(vTPrest AS MONEY) ) 
   from CTRC where EMITENTE= @emite   and
   MONTH(emissaodata)=@mes and status = 'A' 
   and YEAR (EMISSAODATA)= CONVERT (int,@ano) 
   group by xMunIni order by UF,xMunIni
```

This proc returns a table not empty , I use it to create a dataset to fill a rdlc report in C#
      the dataset returns information 
       [image]

I have declared the parameters in the report data

[image]

and this is the code of the reportviewer :

```
 ReportParameter[] p = new ReportParameter[3];
     p[0] = new ReportParameter("emite",EEmit.ToString());
     p[1] = new ReportParameter("mes", emes.ToString());
     p[2] = new ReportParameter("ano", eano.ToString());
     reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(p);
     this.rel_geralACTableAdapter.Fill(this.ifdcontroladoria3DataSet.rel_geralAC,EEmit,emes,eano);
     this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Why doesn't the report show anything?  Thanks.

---

I have deleted the dataset and built again , creating the 3 parameters like text, if I choose integer , the query doesn't work , report parameter only accepts string, but the parameters may be

text,boolen,date/time,integer,float.

Comment: are you assigning a dataset somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 2):

//You're missing a line:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p });
```

//Since you are adding your parameters to a parameter array, you can put the parameter array in //the set parameters class.

//I typically do

```
ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter("ParameterName", "yourtextvalue.text", false);

//repeat again (rp2, rp3, rp4 etc...)
```

//Then call the last statement

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rp, rp2, rp3, rp4 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "false" for Definition all parameters for example:

```
p[0] = new ReportParameter("emite",EEmit.ToString(),false);
```